# Setting up multiple test folders in a SBT project

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

We'd like to set up our [SBT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Build_Tool) project so that we have multiple test folders as opposed to one. So we'd like to see:

- root

  - src

    - test
      - scala
        - unit
        - functional

How would we configure our SBT project file paths to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**SBT 0.9.x**](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/tree/0.9):

```
(sourceDirectories in Test) := Seq(new File("src/test/scala/unit"), 
                                   new File("src/test/scala/functional"))
```

**SBT 0.7.x**:

```
override def testSourceRoots = ("src" / "test") +++ 
       "scala" +++ ("unit" / "functional")
```

Comment: Why are you overriding on 0.7.x but just assigning in 0.9.x?

Comment: Is there any way not to override in 0.7.x? I thought, assignment is possible only in 0.9.x via an introduced concept of project settings.

Comment: Oh, with this edit it makes more sense. You were using `super` before, so I assumed it was intentional.

Comment: I've made it accidentally :-), trying to preserve Java test paths (which is not actually needed here).

Comment: @Daniel ,but I'm still overriding for 0.7.*, and the question remains open :)

Comment: @Vasil You need to override, of course. The difference is whether you reuse the old value (the `super`) or not. Since you were using in one case and not in the other, it confused me.