# Setting up actions for multiple test folders in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

In relation to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6212540/599068), I'd like to have multiple test folders for different types of test and be able to execute the tests contained in each folder with a separate [SBT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Build_Tool) action.

For example, an action 'test-unit' would run only the tests contained under the folder *src/test/scala/unit*, and a 'test-functional' action would run only the tests under *src/test/scala/functional*. How would we write actions to do this?

Answer (score 6):

If you are using `xsbt` 0.10.0, you can easily create [additional test configurations](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Testing) by defining the a full build configuration in a Scala file located in your `project` folder. Below is the wiki example for integration tests. The default directory layout is a bit different from yours, unit tests go in *src/test/scala* and integration tests in *src/it/scala*. From the console, you can then run `test` to execute unit tests or `it:test` for integration tests.

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object B extends Build
{
  lazy val root =
    Project("root", file("."))
      .configs( IntegrationTest )
      .settings( Defaults.itSettings : _*)
      .settings( libraryDependencies += specs )

  lazy val specs = "org.scala-tools.testing" %% "specs" % "1.6.8" % "it"
}
```

Comment: Any idea how to do this in 0.7.7?

Comment: What scala file is this supposed to go in?  It doesn't say.

Comment: File name does not matter as long as it is a .scala file located in the `project` directory. Have a look at Scalaz build file for a more detailed example https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/project/ScalazBuild.scala