# Setting up actions for multiple test folders in SBT using 'Simple' configuration

Tags: scala, environment-variables, integration-testing, sbt, build-tools

This is actually a duplicate of sorts of [Setting up actions for multiple test folders in SBT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224273/setting-up-actions-for-multiple-test-folders-in-sbt), however the answer in that one specifically uses the Scala syntax for SBT.

In our project - currently at SBT 0.10.1, but I hope we can upgrade to 0.11 soon - we use the 'simple' configurating using SBT's own DSL.

How can I create separate testing tasks / commands in SBT for different folders? In my specific case, I'd like a batch of regular unit tests and a batch of integration tests.

A secondary question, is it possible - with SBT - to alter a Java property? For the integration tests, I'd like to set a property called 'env' to 'testing' (or 'integration-testing' soon), so that a different MongoDB database is accessed. When starting up the application, I can do this using -Denv=testing, but is it possible to do this in SBT instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the simple configuration in conjunction with the Scala-based configuration, details are [here](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Getting-Started-Full-Def).  So you should be able to use the advice in the other question and leave your build.sbt untouched or only make minimal changes.  I do this dual configuration frequently to define sub-projects and project dependencies, but keep the simplicity of adding library dependencies.

As for your second question, maybe you should make that a separate question, as I would like to know that as well :)